# Proper flow for git + svn branches?

Tags: svn, git

Is there a proper flow for working with git as a facade for branching on SVN?

Meaning that each git branch is mapped to an SVN branch, so that I can use git's wonderful branching tools to help work on svn branches.

---

**Edit**: I obviously know of the `git svn` tool. I am inquiring specifically about SVN branch related flows.

Comment: The proper flow is using `git-svn` and, eventually, converting the whole repository to git.  You just won't be able to resist...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's the 'git-svn' tool. To see more about this, see git.apache.org, where the ASF infrastructure team maintains a whole slew of git mirrors of svn. At ASF, each user clones a git repo that is set up to support 'git svn dcommit' to commit back to subversion.